# Python 3 Relative Import Inconsistency

Tags: python, import, python-3.6

I just upgraded from Python 2.7 to 3.6 and so far, so good.  I'm trying to follow the guides that that tell about the changes to relative imports, specifically here:

> The only acceptable syntax for relative imports is `from .[module] import name.`
>
> All import forms not starting with . are interpreted as absolute imports.

I tried changing the "from ... import ..." statements in my code to follow the new convention.  Some of the changes worked fine, while others say they can't locate the specified module.

This one works:

[image: source tree (dev.py)]

dev.py (old): `from base import *`
dev.py (new): `from .base import *`

This one doesn't work:

[image: Source tree (urls.py)]

urls.py(old): `from . import views`
urls.py(new): `from .views import *`

Error: `NameError: name 'views' is not defined`

The "old" one works find for urls.py.  I can leave it as-is, but I want to understand why the difference in behavior.  I'd also like to have consistent code.  Any ideas?

Comment: Share project layout, it will help to understand what is wrong

Comment: Because you are not doing the same thing? in urls.py(new) you are not importing views, just the content. Logical, views is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What do you mean by "just the content"?  Also, why does the syntax work for `dev.py`, but not `urls.py`?  FYI, `base.py` is a properties file, containing only variables, no methods.

Comment: @ravioli If you would try to use `base` in dev.py, you would also get the same error. The module object is not imported, only the functions, class and constants the module contains.

Comment: Oh, I see the issue now.  It's with referencing the functions.  When I do `from . import views` I have to specify views.<function_name>.  If I just do `from .views import *`, then I don't need to qualify the function calls -- i.e. just `itemindex` instead of `views.itemindex`.  Thanks for your help!